# GCP App Engine deploy - Failed to build logilab-astng

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform

I'm posting this to hopefully help anyone else with the same problem. I've used the GCP documentation to deploy my python application to GCP App Engine. I was getting the following failure with log out of:

```
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37_app_builder:python37_20190907_3_7_4_RC00" failed: exit status 1
ERROR
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 58, in UserErrorHandler
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 57, in main
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder": exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder": "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder": error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1
Step #1 - "builder":
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
Step #1 - "builder": Failed building wheel for logilab-astng
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder": INFO full build took 24 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO build process for FTL image took 24 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO pip_download_wheels took 19 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1
Step #1 - "builder":
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
Step #1 - "builder": Failed building wheel for logilab-astng
Step #1 - "builder": INFO `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder":
Step #1 - "builder": Failed to build logilab-astng
Step #1 - "builder": Successfully built mysqlclient django-lint pylint logilab-common
Step #1 - "builder": Stored in directory: /tmp/tmp8f2PME/wheel
Step #1 - "builder": Building wheel for logilab-common (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Step #1 - "builder": Building wheel for logilab-common (setup.py): started
Step #1 - "builder": Stored in directory: /tmp/tmp8f2PME/wheel
Step #1 - "builder": Building wheel for pylint (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Step #1 - "builder": Building wheel for pylint (setup.py): started
Step #1 - "builder": Running setup.py clean for logilab-astng
Step #1 - "builder": ----------------------------------------
Step #1 - "builder":
Step #1 - "builder": error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2to3': '2to3'
Step #1 - "builder": running 2to3 on build/lib/logilab/astng/brain
Step #1 - "builder": package init file './test/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
Step #1 - "builder": Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
Step #1 - "builder": Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
```

This took me a little while to track down the issue but logilab-astng relates to pylint and my requirements.txt file contained

```
django-lint==2.0.4
```

after removing this the deployment worked.

If you have to have django-lint then frankly I don't know the solution.

Comment: are you running Standard or Flex environment?